# Add legends to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add legend on ggplot2.

When I use the following codes, I get the following plot.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = (revenue), x = residence), stat="identity", 
           fill="darkgreen", color = "black") +

  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = -(total_spend), x = residence), stat="identity", 
           fill="red", color = "black") +

  geom_line(data = profitCountries, aes(y = total_profit, x = residence, group = 1), size = 1.5,   
            color = "blue"  ) + 

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500000,500000,100000), limits=c(-500000, 500000) ) +
  xlab('Countries') + ggtitle('Campaign spending and revenue by countries') + 
  ylab('Campaign spending                                     Revenue')  + theme_grey()
```

[image: Plot with original colors]

As suggested in other posts, I added `color` inside `aes()`. When I try to do that using the following code, I get the following plot.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = (revenue), x = residence, fill="darkgreen"), stat="identity", 
            color = "black") +

  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = -(total_spend), x = residence, fill="red"), stat="identity", 
            color = "black") +

  geom_line(data = profitCountries, aes(y = total_profit, x = residence, group = 1, color = "blue"), 
  size = 2 ) + 

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500000,500000,100000), limits=c(-500000, 500000) ) +
  xlab('Countries') + ggtitle('Campaign spending and revenue by countries') + 
  ylab('Campaign spending                                     Revenue')  + theme_grey()
```

[image: After adding <code>color</code> inside <code>aes()</code>]

In the second plot, the colors change and two legends are created. Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are currently mapping the character vector green to a manual scale whose colors are automatically determined.

You probably want

```
ggplot(profitCountries, aes(residence)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (revenue), fill="Revenue"), stat="identity", 
            color = "black") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = -(total_spend), fill="Campaign Spending"), stat="identity", 
            color = "black") +   
  geom_line(aes(y = total_profit, group = 1, color = "Net"), size = 2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500000,500000,100000), limits=c(-500000, 500000) ) +
  xlab('Countries') + 
  ggtitle('Campaign spending and revenue by countries') + 
  ylab('Campaign spending                                     Revenue')  + 
  theme_grey() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Revenue" = "darkgreen", "Campaign Spending" = "red")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Net" = "blue"))
```

Comment: This really helps, thank you so much. Is there a way to combine both the legends, as I am currently getting ```fill``` and ```color```? It would be so much better if both could be combined under a common heading ```xyz```.